# Работа в Qt с PySide

Tags: python, qt, pyside

Добрый день.
Решил поработать с Qt и Python (+ с графикой) и не очень понял как их связать. Поставил qt, python 3.2, pyside(в папку питона).
Но я так и не нашел в инете как работать из Qt с питоном.
Судя по структуре PySide он в себе содержит Qt-библиотеки, и непосредственно из qt-creator я не смогу работать с ним?

Работаю под Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неверно понимаете назначение PySide. Это Python биндинг к Qt. Вы пишите под на питоне, который вызывает Qt через PySide. И да, работать из QtCreator у вас не получится, вам нужен  редактор с поддержкой питона.
ЗЫ: PySide это тоже самое что и PyQt только под более свободной лицензией и от создателей Qt.

Comment: А для Qt creator нет расширения чтобы писать на питоне? не знаете?

p.s. Спасибо. Значит я правильно понял PySide

Comment: нету к сожалению) Можете попробовать Eclipse c плагином для питона и для Qt (это если хотите "все в одном"), а так используйте отдельно QtDesigner и отдельно "тысяча и один редактор Python". Как то так.
ЗЫ: мои предпочтения
1) Sublime Text 2 (условно бесплатный, для быстрого и комфортного написания кода)
2) PyCharm (платный, но его авто-дополнение просто ни с чем не сравнимо)
естественно все это чисто лично мое ИМХО. Пробуйте сами, решайте сами...))

Comment: спасибо, будем пробовать